# How can I disable "selection by clicking " on GTK+3 treeview

Tags: python, treeview, gtk3

I have this code where I get a treeview and a sign when I click or move the up / down over the lines. For my application I need to disable the selection when the user clicks on a row, further I wonder if there's any way to block the selection upwards. Thanks

```
    treeview = builder.get_object('treeview3')
    treeview.set_model(liststore)
    select = treeview.get_selection()
    select.connect("changed", on_tree_selection_changed)

def on_tree_selection_changed(selection):
    model, treeiter = selection.get_selected()
    if treeiter != None:
        print "You selected", model[treeiter][0]
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, only doing your signal handler on a double click?

Comment: I need the signal is issued by pressing down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable selections, set the selection mode to None:

```
sel = treeview.get_selection()
sel.set_mode(gtk.SELECTION_NONE)
```

I you want the signal at button pressed:

```
treeview.connect('button-press-event', on_button_press)
```

You will then probably need `convert_widget_to_tree_coords` to convert the coordinates of the button-press to the row in the view.

EDIT: The above is valid for `gtk2`. In `gtk3`, the constant for `set_mode` is called `Gtk.SelectionMode.NONE`. Thanks Lexie.

Comment: Instead of that, I used:
selection =  selection.set_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.NONE)
It works fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, your tag was gtk (and not gtk3), so I thought you were using gtk 2.27 or so....